Why does an argument passed as a variable not show its assigned value in Cypress/Typescript?
I have encountered a peculiar behaviour of Typescript/Cypress. In short, the code is as following

//Step 1: Declares variable
let wireTitle: string = ""


//..test case goes on..//

//Step 2: Assigns value to the variable
cy.get("ol li").first().then((element) => {
            wireTitle = element.find('.prelead-title').text()}


//Step 3: Logs the result to assert the value has displayed correctly
cy.get("ol li").then(() => {console.log(wireTitle)})

//Step 4: Performs the assertion
cy.get("div.prelead-modal-component").contains(wireTitle)


The strange behaviour occurs between steps 3 and 4 - the console displays the variable as having a value assigned, but on running the test case I can see the error cy.contains() cannot be passed an empty string. displayed.
Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this issue?
As I have checked the value in Step 3, I know that the error is not due to the assigning logic not working.
I have done a lot of then() commands as well as forced waits of 4 seconds which did nothing to the result, indicating that the issue is not caused by the asynchronous nature of Cypress.
I also tried different Cypress commands (should()), but the outcome was the same - the value of the variable was an empty string each time

Does this answer your question? Why does Cypress print `cy.log` output later than I would expect?

At step 4 .contains(wireTitle) "captures" the value of wireTitle as it is at the beginning of the test (it's called a closure). Cypress doesn't run the steps individually in the same way javascript does, it builds the command queue from the steps then runs the queue. See Visualize Cypress Command Queue

In step 2 and 3 you have then which awaits the asynchronous operation. But in step 4 you don't, which runs it right away (I assume). So you have a race condition when contains is executed before the assignment.

There is no race condition assuming the thenable returned by get and first follows standard promise semantics. The code in the fulfilment handlers will definitely run after the synchronous code setting them up and calling contains. (not my downvote)

Not sure about what you mean, that the problem is not where I think it is, or that I'm wrong in calling this a "race condition".

"Not sure about what you mean, that the problem is not where I think it is, or that I'm wrong in calling this a "race condition"." The latter. It's not a race condition if the outcome is predetermined. If the then callback is called asynchronously (which is guaranteed with standard promises, even if the promise is already settled), it's impossible for that to run before the call to contains. (Again, though, that's based on the assumption Cypress calls the then callback asynchronously, which I think it does and I'd sure hope it does, but... :-) )

FWIW: I suspect the downvotes are because this sort of thing is very well covered by existing questions and answers and the downvoters think it's a fairly obvious duplicate. Some people downvote even correct answers to questions they consider obvious duplicates. (I don't, but I've seen it done a lot.) Happy coding!

Alright, fair enough. Thanks for the clarification on your comment.

The downvotes are because the answer is incorrect. All Cypress commands are in their own command chain. Step 4 is not executed until after Step 3. However, as @Aladin points out above, the value of  wireTitle is taken before Step 3 is executed.
